# Get first value and last value

Tags: sql, string, oracle

i have below record like '8|12|53|123|97' and i need to find the range of values between 8 to 97, so that i need the number 8 and 97.

Comment: Never store multiple values in a single column. Change your table design!

Comment: Its a character column and i just want to split it so that i can able to process the range between first value which is 8 and last value which is 97

Comment: Good luck with that but storing data like this will only give you problems.

Comment: This structure is not in [First Normal Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form). I know proper data modelling is boring and not in fashion, but it does prevent knotty problems like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `REGEXP_SUBSTR` as following:

> ```
> SQL> SELECT
>   2      REGEXP_SUBSTR('8|12|53|123|97', '^[0-9]+') FIRSTVAL,
>   3      REGEXP_SUBSTR('8|12|53|123|97', '[0-9]+$') LASTVAL
>   4  FROM
>   5      DUAL;
>
> FIRSTVAL   LASTVAL
> ---------- ----------
> 8          97
>
> SQL>
> ```

- `^` matches the beginning of a string.
- `$` matches the end of a string.

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution which will work for any string which has at least one pipe.

```
with cte as (
  select '8|12|53|123|97' str from dual
  )
, rng as (  
select to_number(substr(str, 1, instr(str, '|')-1)) as token_1
      ,to_number(substr(str, instr(str, '|', -1)+1)) as token_2
from cte )
select token_1 + level - 1 as tkn
from rng
connect by level <= (token_2 - token_1) + 1
/
```

The first subquery is just your test data. The second subquery identifies the first number (`token_1`) and the last number (`token_2`) in the string. It uses `substr()` and `instr()` just because they are faster than regex. `instr()` with a negative offset finds the last occurence of the search argument.

The main query generates a range of numbers from the bounds of the `rng` subquery. Not sure if that's in your requirement (depends on what you mean by *"range of values between"*).

Because this model is not in [First Normal Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form) you are exposed to data quality issues. The query will not produce results if the first or last tokens are not numeric, or there's only one token or the separator is not a pipe.